# cl_khr_gl_sharing is supported for Pentium G860 but not for Core i7-4960X

Tags: opencl

I have two computers, one with a GTX 980 + Intel Core i7 4960X and the other one has a AMD Radeon HD 7850 + Pentium G860. I am getting device features with opencl's `clGetDeviceInfo` function. I am wondering why the Penitum G860 is supporting `cl_khr_gl_sharing` extension and Core i7-4960X is not supporting in OpenCL.

Is that something related to difference between AMD and nVIDIA graphic cards? or it is really the difference between cpus? Because definitely, Core i7-4960 is much much more powerful than Pentium G860.

Intel OpenCL Drivers are installed on both computers. For the nVIDIA system, I am using nvidia opencl 1.1 driver but for AMD one, I am using AMD APP SDK 3.0. Can be some difference due to that?

Comment: Have you tried to install the Intel OpenCL driver?

Comment: @Christian yes! on both computers the intel opencl drivers are installed!

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the CPU device from AMD's runtime? The device's name there is still Pentium there.

Comment: @Lrdx what do you mean by AMD Runtime? I am using AMD driver and the device name is Pentium G860 which is my cpu.

Comment: @mmostajab Use [GPU Caps Viewer](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/) to make sure `cl_khr_gl_sharing` is not really supported. In my case both nvidia and intel platform show `cl_khr_gl_sharing` is supported (nvs5200M + i7-3520M)

Comment: @Doqtor As I experienced, I made gl buffers on Pentium CPU, it was working but everything was slow. So, instead of using `cl_khr_gl_sharing` to separate my devices in two groups, opengl support and no opengl support, I am using `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU` and `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU`. So, for sure the cpu ones are not supporting gl, and gpu ones are supporting. I think this is the only way to group the device in gl support and not support correctly.

Comment: @mmostajab Both AMD and Intel has an OpenCL platform, both has support for CPU devices. The AMD platform's CPU device works perfectly fine on Intel CPUs as well. So the question is if you are using Intel or AMD OpenCL driver on the CPU.

Comment: @Lrdx I have installed Intel OpenCL 2.0 runtime driver. So, I am using the intel one.

Comment: Sigh. You **also** installed AMD OpenCL 2.0 runtime (that includes a CPU device as well) when you installed the driver for the AMD graphics card. You have to check clGetPlatformInfo with CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR to see what platform are you using. If it is indeed AMD, then the answer to your question is that you were using a totally different implementation of OpenCL on the two computers, so they can support different things.

Comment: @Lrdx yes! It is under AMD Platform. So, I am not using the installed intel opencl driver at all on my pc which has AMD GPU.

Comment: Are you using the default platform? I would recommend against doing that, and query/select the cl_platform manually (don't pass null). On the other hand, I've found AMD's implementation being just as fine, if not better, even on Intel CPUs because you could share contexts with the GPU. As far as I know, only missing feature of AMD's runtime on Intel CPUs is the lack of AVX2 usage, but the Pentium is not capable of that anyway.

Comment: yes, I am using the default platform on AMD. Actually in my application, it is creating a device context for each device, so I am able to change from amd platform's intel cpu device to intel's platform intel cpu :)
Also, I found no performance improvement in sharing the opengl context between the intel cpu and amd gpu. So, it is totally useless